# Determine if the focused control is an Editable one?

Tags: windows, winapi, textbox, controls

Using **pure Win32 API**, how can I get the handle to the control that currently has the focus? And then how can I determine if it's a Text Box / Rich Text Box?

I'm trying to write a small macro keys program which will allow user to register new hot keys using the RegisterHotKey() function. Everything is working fine except that I don't want to violently call SetWindowText() or SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, TEXT("Something")) without knowing whether the control is a text box or not.

Be noted that I want a handle to the **control** that currently has the focus, **not the whole window** the user is working on.

Comment: Use the accessibility interfaces.

Comment: Can you tell me more about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592(v=vs.85).aspx).